# Hide an attribute when another attibute is enabled and vice versa Magento2.3.4-p2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.4-p2

I am using Magento Version 2.3.4-p2.

I need to hide **sku** attribute if another **status** attribute is enabled and vice versa in cart price rule form backend.

I need to change in xml file. Kindly check the below code and confirm.

**app/code/Namespace/Promotions/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_rule_form.xml**

```
 <fieldset name="rule_information" sortOrder="10">
    
            <field name="sku" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sku</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Literature SKU</label>
                    <visible>true</visible>
                    <dataScope>sku</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
    
            <field name="status" formElement="checkbox">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Status</label>       
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <checkbox>
                        <settings>
                            <valueMap>
                                <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                                <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                            </valueMap>
                            <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                        </settings>
                    </checkbox>
                </formElements>
            </field>       
        </fieldset>
```

if anyone have any idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
    
            <field name="sku" formElement="input">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">sku</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>text</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Literature SKU</label>
                    <visible>true</visible>
                    <dataScope>sku</dataScope>
                </settings>
            </field>
    
            <field name="status" formElement="checkbox">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                    <label translate="true">Status</label>
                   <exports>
                        <link name="checked">ns = ${ $.ns }, index = sku :visible</link>
                    </exports>       
                </settings>
                <formElements>
                    <checkbox>
                        <settings>
                            <valueMap>
                                <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                                <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                            </valueMap>
                            <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                        </settings>
                    </checkbox>
                </formElements>
            </field>       
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :)